# Did i misunderstand anything when flagging this answer?

Tags: discussion

I recently flagged an answer that were really poor, consisting of a one-liner with no real context more than a pointer and a link.

The answer were something similar to this:

> "You can use XXX to achieve this. Take a look at this [Link].

And it were declined.

> Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it.

According to SharePoint StackExchanges Help Center about answering, the following is stated:

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

And with the following pointer:

```
"Barely more than a link to an external site."
```

Did i misunderstand anything about the above when flagging the answer?

Comment: Would you link to a sample answer you flagged?

Comment: No, I do not wanna point fingers on another member, so the example in my question is all i will provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like a moderator was to quick to decline. Link only answers are invalid here as link usually breaks in the future. It could also be that the answer is very old (5 years or more), and was the accepted answer back then.

But please keep those flags coming, and I'll advice myself and fellow mods to evaluate flags more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Benny!

Comment: Should i flag link only answer as "Not an answer" or "Low quality"? My evety flag to link only answers are declined.

Comment: @AakashMorya As it's technically an answer, flag it by using "Low Quality". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"You can use XXX" *is* an answer. A poor answer, but an answer. The addition of a link doesn't make it any *less* of an answer.

See [Your Answer Is in Another Castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/147191), and read it carefully.

Comment: Based on what @Christoffer posted, an answer with that format would be too poor quality to keep. As you said, it's not about it _being_ an answer it's just doesn't [meet StackExchange standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).